# How to delete old log files with logrotate

Tags: logrotate

In my CentOS, there is a Logstash, which generate many log files. Here is how the log files look like:

```
logstash-2023-03-09.log  logstash-2023-03-20.log                   logstash-deprecation-2023-03-08-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-14-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-25-1.log.gz
logstash-2023-03-10.log  logstash-2023-03-21.log                   logstash-deprecation-2023-03-09-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-15-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-26-1.log.gz
logstash-2023-03-11.log  logstash-2023-03-22.log                   logstash-deprecation-2023-03-10-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-16-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-27-1.log.gz
logstash-2023-03-12.log  logstash-2023-03-23.log                   logstash-deprecation.log                  logstash-plain-2023-03-17-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-28-1.log.gz
logstash-2023-03-13.log  logstash-2023-03-24.log                   logstash-json.log                         logstash-plain-2023-03-18-1.log.gz  logstash-plain.log
logstash-2023-03-14.log  logstash-2023-03-25.log                   logstash-plain-2023-03-07-1.log.gz        logstash-plain-2023-03-19-1.log.gz  logstash-slowlog-json.log
logstash-2023-03-15.log  logstash-2023-03-26.log                   logstash-plain-2023-03-09-1.log.gz        logstash-plain-2023-03-20-1.log.gz  logstash-slowlog-plain.log
logstash-2023-03-16.log  logstash-2023-03-27.log                   logstash-plain-2023-03-10-1.log.gz        logstash-plain-2023-03-21-1.log.gz
logstash-2023-03-17.log  logstash-2023-03-28.log                   logstash-plain-2023-03-11-1.log.gz        logstash-plain-2023-03-22-1.log.gz
logstash-2023-03-18.log  logstash-2023-03-29.log                   logstash-plain-2023-03-12-1.log.gz        logstash-plain-2023-03-23-1.log.gz
logstash-2023-03-19.log  logstash-deprecation-2023-03-07-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-13-1.log.gz        logstash-plain-2023-03-24-1.log.gz
```

All of these are generated by Logstash.

Now I want to use `logrotate` on them to remove the old files.

Here is my config of `logrotate`:

```
[envoy@mirror-dfh0splogv logstash]$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/logstash
/var/log/logstash/logstash-20*.log {
    daily
    rotate 15
    compress
    delaycompress
}

/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain*.log.gz {
    daily
    rotate 5
}
```

What I want is quite simple. For the `logstash-20*.log` files, I only want to keep the 15 latest files. And for the `logstash-plain*.log.gz`, I only want to keep the 5 latest.

However, when I execute the command `logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/logstash`, all of filenames are appended with `.1` and none of files are removed:

```
logstash-2023-03-09.log.1  logstash-2023-03-20.log.1  logstash-deprecation-2023-03-07-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-13-1.log.gz.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-24-1.log.gz.1
logstash-2023-03-10.log.1  logstash-2023-03-21.log.1  logstash-deprecation-2023-03-08-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-14-1.log.gz.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-25-1.log.gz.1
logstash-2023-03-11.log.1  logstash-2023-03-22.log.1  logstash-deprecation-2023-03-09-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-15-1.log.gz.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-26-1.log.gz.1
logstash-2023-03-12.log.1  logstash-2023-03-23.log.1  logstash-deprecation-2023-03-10-1.log.gz  logstash-plain-2023-03-16-1.log.gz.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-27-1.log.gz.1
logstash-2023-03-13.log.1  logstash-2023-03-24.log.1  logstash-deprecation.log                  logstash-plain-2023-03-17-1.log.gz.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-28-1.log.gz.1
logstash-2023-03-14.log.1  logstash-2023-03-25.log.1  logstash-json.log                         logstash-plain-2023-03-18-1.log.gz.1  logstash-plain.log
logstash-2023-03-15.log.1  logstash-2023-03-26.log.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-07-1.log.gz.1      logstash-plain-2023-03-19-1.log.gz.1  logstash-slowlog-json.log
logstash-2023-03-16.log.1  logstash-2023-03-27.log.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-09-1.log.gz.1      logstash-plain-2023-03-20-1.log.gz.1  logstash-slowlog-plain.log
logstash-2023-03-17.log.1  logstash-2023-03-28.log.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-10-1.log.gz.1      logstash-plain-2023-03-21-1.log.gz.1
logstash-2023-03-18.log.1  logstash-2023-03-29.log    logstash-plain-2023-03-11-1.log.gz.1      logstash-plain-2023-03-22-1.log.gz.1
logstash-2023-03-19.log.1  logstash-2023-03-29.log.1  logstash-plain-2023-03-12-1.log.gz.1      logstash-plain-2023-03-23-1.log.gz.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is in the log4j2 configuration within the application, see [for
example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46368163/5008284):

```
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d
```

To get `logrotate` to remove files that have effectively already been
rotated by logstash, you need to convince it that the old log files were
really created by itself. So, for an old file such as
`logstash-2023-03-09.log`, you need to say that the original file to rotate was
`logstash`, and the rotation mechanism to use is to add the date extension
format `-%Y-%m-%d.log`. This results in a configuration file something like

```
# for eg logstash-2023-03-09.log
"logstash" {
 dateext
 dateformat -%Y-%m-%d.log
 daily
 rotate 15
}
```

For this to work, even with `--force`, the "trigger" file `logstash` has to exist,
so it needs to be created empty by hand before the first run. Since it will be
rotated to, say, `logstash-2023-04-01.log` if that is today's date, we also
need the `create` option to recreate the trigger file. We also
need to remove the bogus renamed file. The configuration file might become:

```
# for eg logstash-2023-03-09.log
"logstash" {
 dateext
 dateformat -%Y-%m-%d.log
 daily
 rotate 15
 create
 postrotate
  f=logstash-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log; [ ! -s "$f" ] && rm "$f"
 endscript
}
```

We check that the file to remove is empty, in case the logging application
actually created it first, in which case logrotate will not have rotated
the trigger file.

A similar entry for the files such as `logstash-plain-2023-03-25-1.log.gz`
might be:

```
# for eg logstash-plain-2023-03-25-1.log.gz
"logstash-plain" {
 dateext
 dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-1.log.gz
 daily
 rotate 5
 create
 postrotate
  f=logstash-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-1.log.gz; [ ! -s "$f" ] && rm "$f"
 endscript
}
```

The trigger file `logstash-plain` will also have to be created by hand.

This is something of a hack, so do experiment with copies of the files in a
separate directory, and without using `--force`. Wait 24 hours for a second
run, and use `-v` to get confirmation of what is happening.